# Subtracting DATETIME from future date - PHP

Tags: php, counter

I have a datetime in my database that is stored whenever a user lists an item for auction. I'm trying to make a timer of some sort that will show users how much longer the auction will last. I'm assuming I should subtract the datetime from some future date and echo out the result. If there's a better way to do this -- which I'm sure there is -- please let me know.

This is the code I've been attempting to use. At the moment, the result is a long number that never changes.

```
$expireDay=strtotime('2015-07-20 20:12:50');
$theDay=strtotime($row['dateadded']);
$timeToEnd=$expireDay - $theDay;
echo "$timeToEnd";
```

Comment: `strtotime` returns the number of seconds between the two dates. You're subtracting two static dates so the number wouldn't change.  I think `$theDay` should be the current date and time not when it was added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need [DateTime::diff](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php).

```
$expireDay=new DateTime('2015-07-20 20:12:50');
$theDay=new DateTime('now');
$timeToEnd=$expireDay->diff($theDay);
echo $timeToEnd->format('%R%a days');
```

Comment: For a moment, I thought this was working perfectly, but it appears that $timetoEnd is showing a negative number.

Comment: @LuluSparks, you might need to swap `$theDay` and `$expireDay` like this: `$timeToEnd=$theDay->diff($expireDay);`

Answer (score 1):

What you intended to do was

```
$expireDay=strtotime('2015-07-20 20:12:50');
$theDay=time();
$timeToEnd=$expireDay - $theDay;
echo "$t
```

As it was you were subtracting two constants.  It has to be compare with the current time.